# Get 404 for url specified in module.routing.yml

Tags: 8, uri

I am new to Drupal and I got stuck with the problem that I don't know how to debug even: 
I have made a simple module 'final', its structure:

```
Applications/MAMP/htdocs/drupal_dir_1/modules/final > ls
final.info.yml    final.routing.yml src

/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/drupal_dir_1/modules/final > ls src/Controller/
ExampleController.php
```

Files contents:

```
> cat final.info.yml
name: Final
type: module
description: This is an final module
core: 8.x⏎

> cat final.routing.yml
final.content:
  path: '/final'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\final\Controller\ExampleController::content'
    _title: 'Hello world bitch!'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'

> cat src/Controller/ExampleController.php
<?php
namespace Drupal\final\Controller;
use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
class ExampleController extends ControllerBase {
  public function content() {
    $build = [
      '#markup' => $this->t('Hello World, bitch!'),
    ];
return $build;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you did not install the module

if you tried to install you would get

```
drush en final
```

> ParseError: syntax error, unexpected 'final' (T_FINAL), expecting identifier (T_STRING) in /home/giorgos/share/gwebsites/dru8.dev/web/modules/custom/final/src/Controller/ExampleController.php on line 2 #0 /home/giorgos/share/gwebsites/dru8.dev/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(322): Composer\Autoload\includeFile('/home/giorgos/s...')
>    #1 [internal function]: Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass('Drupal\final\Co...')
>   ...

`final` is [reserved keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php) thus it confuses the php parser when it sees

```
namespace Drupal\final\Controller;
```

Can also be caught with my vscode setup and linter

[image]

You have to change `final` to something else but then you have to rename it elsewhere in your module (folder name, file names, reference to the class etc)

Otherwise the module is working fine.

Comment: Thank you very much! Kind of unexpected problem)